# Angular 2 and Resolve route

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular and I am pretty new on it. I want to display some data in a view, and the data comes from the server, I know that it is async so I have been trying to use resolves to get data before view render, but I cannot get it in the component, this is what I've done.

MateriasResolve.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Materias } from './materias.model';

@Injectable()
export class MateriasResolve implements Resolve<any> {

      public user_id = localStorage.getItem('userid');
      public colegio = localStorage.getItem('colegio');

      constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

      resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
      return this.userService.getTeacherMaters(this.user_id, this.colegio).map(data => {
  console.log(data); >>here i get the data in the console, no problem here
}).first();
}

}
```

the service:

```
getTeacherMaters(id, colegio_code) {
    this.auth.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.get(globals.API_DOMAIN + "/materias/" + id + "/" + colegio_code, this.auth.options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

and my part of my component:

```
getMaterias() {
this.materias = this.userService.getTeacherMaters(this.user_id, this.colegio)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("data ------------- " + data);
    return data.materias;
  });
console.log(this.materias);
}
```

I need to put the data in the materias var, but all I get in the console.log is:

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

First, you are mapping the data that comes from `getTeacherMaters` but you are not returning any data so it is most likely falling through here. You need to update it to this:

```js
return this.userService.getTeacherMaters(this.user_id, this.colegio).map(data => {
  console.log(data); >>here i get the data in the console, no problem here
  return data;
}).first();
```

Second, you are saving a copy of the subscription but I suspect that you want to save the data to `this.materias`. Because the data request is async you will not get the data until inside of the `subscribe` block and calling `subscribe` will return a subscription that you can cancel. Update your `getMaterias` method to be:

```js
getMaterias() {
    this.userService.getTeacherMaters(this.user_id, this.colegio)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.materias = data;
            console.log(this.materias);
         });
}
```